# Android Network Information: Displaying type, if connected, speed, signal, etc

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I've been search and looking through forums and postings for tutorial(s) on, I think I am looking in the right direction. ConnectivyManager and TelephonyManager. I have tried looking at the Android Documents, yet as self explanatory as they are, I still get lost. Doing the self thought thing, I ry to find tutorials that break it down and show how to use and how things work.

What it is I'm wanting to do, is a full screen app that displays if your on 1x, 3g, 4g etc.. also the data transfer rate sending and receiving. (basically the same stuff in Setting>About Phone>Network) going to have it play a sound with each change in network type and change an image...

copying and pasting code from pages really don't help me learn what I'm doing, or to understand it. If anyone might know of any good tutorials or the direction i need to go in would be awesome, it would get me out of this rut I've been stuck in searching for for a few nights now lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) and [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) classes are your friend here. Read over the [available public methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#pubmethods) to get an idea what's possible.

Here's a brief code sample that demonstrates how to determine if there is an active network connection:

```
/**
 * Determine if the device has an active network connection.
 * @return true if the network is connected, false if otherwise.
 */
private boolean isConnected() {
    final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm != null) {
        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            return activeNetwork.isConnected();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it was, sorry for taking so long to accept it lol now on to the next hard task with this lol